# combinations of letters using itertools in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am trying to use itertools.combinations to return all the combinations of letters in alphabet with length at most n.

```
def string_combinations(alphabet, n):
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    alphabet : {str}
    n : {int}

    Returns
    -------
    list : {list} of {str}    

    Example
    -------
    >>> string_combinations('abc', 2)
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc']
    '''
```

So far I have

```
return [str(x) for i in range(1,n+1) for x in itertools.combinations(alphabet,i)]
```

but `itertools.combinations` returns tuples in a list `[('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]` How should I achieve my desired solution?

Comment: So, `itertools` does what you need. What's the problem?

Comment: I am trying to get a list containing all the combinations, eg. ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc']. I am getting [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')] which is not what I want. @ForceBru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all the strings returned by `itertools`:

```
result = map("".join, (comb for i in range(1, n+1) for comb in itertools.combinations(alphabet, i)))
```

This is equivalent to putting a call to `"".join` inside a list comprehension:

```
result = ["".join(comb) for ...]
```

`"".join(iterable)` concatenates all the string that are retrieved from an iterable:

```
"".join(('a', 'b', 'c')) == "abc"
```